# Rails Tutorial Chapter 7 user saves without email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've been going thru Rails Tutorial and got stucked on chapter 7. The problem is that after posting sign up information to rails thru rails console (with User.new), id, created_at and updated_at are becoming nil. By creating User thru creaded user web page, email becomes nil.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase! }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_secure_password
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                               :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

*** new.html.erb ***

```
<% provide(:titel, 'Sign Up') %>

<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**rails console output**

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.new(name: "Test User", email: "test@user.com", password: "secretsecret", password_confirmation: "secretsecret")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Test User", email: "test@user.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$E1SvEDh.aQSi809sQ7ecReacmSsnxRDUn3IbEawugQD...">
```

**Showing /sample_app/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #7 raised:**

```
def gravatar_for(user, size: 100)
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase) # this line is highlighted
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?=#{size}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

by checking development.sqlite3, email field is nil.

Where am I wrong? Thank you!

Ruby 2.4, Rail 5.1

Comment: Did you try with `save`? `User.new(name: "Test User", email: "test@user.com", password: "secretsecret", password_confirmation: "secretsecret").save`

Comment: of course I tried it! over rails console mode it seems to function well, but thru web interface email field is stil staying nil...

Comment: Just to know, do you have a repo, to see where's the problem?

Comment: It seems the repo isn't updated.

Comment: How are posting you the new user to the controller?

Comment: oh, you'r right. here is updated one https://bitbucket.org/CasusArts/sample_app/src/c51644815432?at=master

Comment: The controller you points your login route, doesn't exist, what to do?

Comment: login controller is not necessary at this point. it'll come soon. the problem now is that by saving user data over web interface email field is saved as nil. whith console it's not a problem however..

Answer (score 0):

`User.new` does not actually make a post request to the controller. It just creates a new instance of the User object in memory without saving it to the database. If you use `User.create` with the same arguments you will get an id, an updated at, and a created_at - but this still is not making a post request to your controller, its simply saving it to your database. If you'd like to make a post request to the new action of your controller you can make a front end with a new user form and submit it, or you could use something like postman or curl to make a request to your server. You'd also have to have your serving running either locally or elsewhere. I recommend reviewing pure ruby before going deeper into rails.

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/3/

https://www.getpostman.com/

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 0):

After long time seeking for errror, it's finaly cought! The main casus on it were `before_save { self.email = email.downcase! }` pice of code. in user.rb model.`before_save { self.email = email.downcase }`, so, without forcing downcase!